# Query to Find minimum date in group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following query;

```
SELECT id, MIN(updated_at) 
FROM accounts 
GROUP BY mem_id, account, sub_account 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Simple statement to find duplicates by grouping the selected fields and printing the `id` and smallest `updated_at` value amongst those groupings.

The problem I encounter is it will print the smallest `updated_at` value but the `id` that is printed with it may be associated with the other duplicate entry in some rows.

It seems as though it is selecting the `id` in each grouping separately (and randomly) from the minimum `updated_at` value. How can I get the intended behavior of aquiring the `id` associated with the minimum `updated_at` value every time?

Example Data:

```
(id, mem_id, account, sub_account, updated_at) VALUES (2351, 12, 123456, 12345, 2016-04-30)

(id, mem_id, account, sub_account, updated_at) VALUES (7638, 12, 123456, 12345, 2016-06-15)
```

My objective here is to get the `id` of the `updated_at` value amongst these two that is the minimum value. Therefore I want `id 2351` but in some rows, it will return the other id randomly.

Comment: show us sample data, current and expected result   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Added in some more explanation.

Comment: Do you have any PK there?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The PK is the id field and the end goal here is to add a key for uniqueness amongst the 3 group by fields. For now I'm just trying to get rid of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you must use a subselect and another group by

```
select id, update_at 
from accounts 
where update_at in  ( 
    select MIN(updated_at) 
    FROM accounts 
    GROUP BY mem_id, account, sub_account 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

Comment: My updated_at values are not unique to each id though. They are simply timestamp values, and my objective is to remove the oldest duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The query I ended up using that worked for the most part was this;

```
SELECT a.* from accounts a
JOIN
(
SELECT *, MIN(updated_at) min_date
FROM accounts 
GROUP BY mem_id, account, sub_account 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b
ON 
a.mem_id = b.mem_id 
AND 
a.account = b.account 
AND 
a.sub_account = b.sub_account 
AND 
a.updated_at = b.min_date
```

Basically does a self-join to get the minimum value of `updated_at` for each grouping then matches the rows based on the different info about them. In my case there was only ever 1 duplicate for each entry so this may not work for cases involving multiple duplicates. Then I just used that listing to delete the accounts that I needed to delete.